# SQL Query to return all rows with the earliest date available for each year

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am trying to design a SQL query that can return the records for the earliest date in each year. Suppose I have a table as follows:

```
Date       | Category | Value
========== | ======== | =====
2019-01-03 | Apple    | 5
2019-01-03 | Orange   | 2
2019-01-20 | Apple    | 5
2019-01-20 | Orange   | 8
2019-02-05 | Apple    | 1
2019-02-05 | Peach    | 5
2018-01-02 | Apple    | 2
2018-01-02 | Orange   | 9
2018-05-10 | Apple    | 3
2018-05-10 | Orange   | 5
2018-07-20 | Apple    | 6
2018-07-20 | Orange   | 1
```

I am trying to generate a table shown below:

```
Date       | Category | Value
========== | ======== | =====
2019-01-03 | Apple    | 5
2019-01-03 | Orange   | 2
2018-01-02 | Apple    | 2
2018-01-02 | Orange   | 9
```

The earliest date for each year will change, which means I cannot simply query by day & month. I have tried using:

```
SELECT MIN(Date), * 
FROM mytable 
GROUPBY YEAR(Date)
```

But this results in an aggregate error: 'Category' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: which rdms are you actually using?

Comment: My DB is running in Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.date = (select min(t2.date)
                from mytable t2
                where t2.category = t.category and year(t2.date) = year(t.date)
               );
```

You can also use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by category, year(date) order by date) as seqnum
      from mytable t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one possiblity

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable  (
>   [Date] VARCHAR(10),
>   [Category] VARCHAR(6),
>   [Value] INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO mytable 
>   ([Date], [Category], [Value])
> VALUES
>   ('2019-01-03', 'Apple', '5'),
>   ('2019-01-03', 'Orange', '2'),
>   ('2019-01-20', 'Apple', '5'),
>   ('2019-01-20', 'Orange', '8'),
>   ('2019-02-05', 'Apple', '1'),
>   ('2019-02-05', 'Peach', '5'),
>   ('2018-01-02', 'Apple', '2'),
>   ('2018-01-02', 'Orange', '9'),
>   ('2018-05-10', 'Apple', '3'),
>   ('2018-05-10', 'Orange', '5'),
>   ('2018-07-20', 'Apple', '6'),
>   ('2018-07-20', 'Orange', '1');
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 12 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT t1.*
> FROM mytable t1 INNER JOIN
> (SELECT MIN([Date]) mindate,[Category]
> FROM mytable
> GROUP BY 
> [Category], YEAR([Date])) t2
> ON t1.[Category] = t2.[Category] AND t1.[Date] = t2.mindate
> ;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Date       | Category | Value
> :--------- | :------- | ----:
> 2019-01-03 | Apple    |     5
> 2019-01-03 | Orange   |     2
> 2019-02-05 | Peach    |     5
> 2018-01-02 | Apple    |     2
> 2018-01-02 | Orange   |     9
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ccadb538937918e1b699dd10306ac3c4)*